# MongoDb Aggregate on both field and a nested array field in the same record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection. I am trying to get an aggregate sum/count of a field in the record. I also need an  aggregate sum/count of a nested array field  in the record.
 I am using MongoDB 3.0.0 with Jongo.

**Please find my record below:**

> db.events.insert([{
>
> ```
> "eventId": "a21sda2s-711f-12e6-8bcf-p1ff819aer3o",
> "orgName": "ORG1",
> "eventName": "EVA2",
> "eventCost": 5000,
> "bids": [{
>         "vendorName": "v1",
>         "bidStatus": "ACCEPTED",
>         "bidAmount": 4400
>     },{
>         "vendorName": "v2",
>         "bidStatus": "PROCESSING",
>         "bidAmount": 4900
>     },{
>         "vendorName": "v3",
>         "bidStatus": "REJECTED",
>         "bidAmount": "3000"
>     }] }, {
> "eventId": "4427f318-7699-11e5-8bcf-feff819cdc9f",
> "orgName": "ORG1",
> "eventName": "EVA3",
> "eventCost": 1000,
> "bids": [ {
>         "vendorName": "v1",
>         "bidStatus": "REJECTED",
>         "bidAmount": 800
>     }, {
>         "vendorName": "v2",
>         "bidStatus": "PROCESSING",
>         "bidAmount": 900
>     },{
>         "vendorName": "v3",
>         "bidStatus": "PROCESSING",
>         "bidAmount": 990
>     }] }])
> ```

I need  $eventCount and $eventCost where I aggregate $eventCost field.
I get $acceptedCount and $acceptedAmount by aggregating $bids.bidAmount field (with a condition on $bids.bidStatus)

**The result I need would be in form:**

```
[
{
"_id" : "EVA2",
"eventCount" : 2,
"eventCost" : 10000,
"acceptedCount" : 2,
"acceptedAmount" : 7400 },
{ 
"_id" : "EVA3",
"eventCount" : 1,
"eventCost" : 1000 ,
 "acceptedCount" : 0,
"acceptedAmount" : 0 },
}]
```

I am not able to get the result in a single query. Right now I make two Queries A and Query B(refer below) and merge them in my Java Code. 
I use an $unwind operator in my Query B.

Is there a way I can the achieve the same result, in a single query. I feel all I need is a way to pass the bids[] array downstream for the next operation in the pipeline.

I tried $push operator, but I am not able to figure, a way to push the entire bid[] array downstream.

I don't want to change my record structure, but if there is something intrinsically wrong, I could give it a try. Thanks for all your help.

### My Solution

**Query A:**

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: "$eventName",
        eventCount:     {$sum: 1}, // Get count of all events
        eventCost: {$sum: "$eventCost"} // Get sum of costs
    } }
])
```

**Query B:**

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$bids" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$eventName",
        // Get Count of Bids that have been accepted
        acceptedCount:{ $sum:{$cond: [{$eq: ["$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED"]} ,1,0] } } ,
        // Get Sum of Amounts that have been accepted
        acceptedAmount:{$sum:{$cond: [{$eq: ["$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED"]} ,"$bids.bidAmount",0]

    } } } }  
])
```

Join Query A and QueryB in Java Code.

**What I need:**

A single DB operation to accomplish the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with unwinding arrays is it's going to mess up your count's for the grouped events if you try to unwind these before you do that initial grouping, as the number of items in each document array will affect the count and sum with the deformalized documents.

Provided that is practical for your data size, there is however nothing wrong with using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to simply create and "array" of "arrays", where of course you just process [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) twice on each grouped document:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$eventName",
        "eventCount": { "$sum": 1 },
        "eventCost": { "$sum": "$eventCost" },
        "bids": { "$push": "$bids" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$bids" },
    { "$unwind": "$bids" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "eventCount": { "$first": "$eventCount" },
        "eventCost": { "$first": "$eventCost" },
        "acceptedCount":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "acceptedCost":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED" ] },
                    "$bids.bidAmount",
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

The likely better alternative to this is to sum up the "accepted" values from each document first, and then sum those values per "event" later:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$bids" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "eventName": { "$first": "$eventName" },
        "eventCost": { "$first": "$eventCost" },
        "acceptedCount":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "acceptedCost":{
            "$sum":{
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$bids.bidStatus","ACCEPTED" ] },
                    "$bids.bidAmount",
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$eventName",
        "eventCount": { "$sum": 1 },
        "eventCost": { "$sum": "$eventCost" },
        "acceptedCount": { "$sum": "$acceptedCount" },
        "acceptedCost": { "$sum": "$acceptedCost" }
    }}
])
```

In that way each array is reduced to just the values you need to collect and this makes the latter `$group` a lot easier.

Those are a couple of approaches with the latter being the better option, but if you are actually able to process both queries in parallel and combine them in a smart way, then running two queries as you are currently doing would be my recommended approach for the best performance.

Comment: Wow, that's a good way to use the $first, Thanks for the answer . I am using the second way in the answer